# complete all graduation requirement but delay in degree award

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have received the phd progrom admission offer with TA fellowship, which will start in 2019 Fall semester.
For undergrad degree, I tried to graduate in this summer and I finished all the requirements.
But for some classes, the final grades were entered too late before the degree award date for summer graduation, so I could not get my official degree certificate before this winter.
My undergrad school awards degree only three times in an academic year - May, August, December.
The school graduation coordinator can write the letter that I have completed all but the degree will be actually awarded in December.

What I worry is, just after I accepted the admission offer, the grad school only has asked to submit the official transcript whether the coursework is still ongoing or not.
They said, if the degree is awarded after I gave them the official transcript, I have to submit the official transcript with all final grades and proof of degree before the second semester registration.
The second semester, 2020 Spring, will start mid-January, and I can get my degree in mid-December and send the degree certificate no later than early January.
And right now I do not need any additional coursework in 2019 Fall in my undergrad school.

I asked the grad school office and they seemed to forward it to the department which I will join their phd program.
The department said they will write a petition for me but this matter is behest of the graduate school if they accept the petition or not.
Based on what the department said, it is the grad school who has the authority over this matter, but I did not get a reply from the grad school.
Instead, it seemed that the grad school just forwarded my email to the department.

I cannot get any clear answer for this, so I wonder if there is anyone who experiences a similar thing to my situation....

Comment: What is your problem, they clearly told you that you can submit the official transcript & proof « before the second semester registration » so do that.

Comment: @SolarMike: I presume that *registration* for the second semester takes place well before the second semester actually starts, i.e. well before January, which is the soonest that OP can submit the degree certificate.

Comment: It sounds like, as the department said, it will be necessary to petition the graduate school for an exception.  Even if they are not willing to discuss it with you informally by email, they should consider a formal petition, so that seems like the route you have to take.  I think it's likely that the petition would be granted, since you can show that you have completed all the requirements, and the delay in getting the actual document is purely bureaucratic and outside your control.

Comment: @NateEldredge OP does not give the registration dates, some places registration is completed in the first week and can be completed as late as week 4 or 5. Again making assumptions on poor info...

Comment: Answers can only come from the institution. Nobody here can help. It is up to their rules and possibly their willingness to bend them. Seek help there.